# Pandas.Dataframe.duplicated() includes missing rows as duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a Pandas Dataframe named `Merged` that has an attribute named `RegimentalNumber`.

I'm using the `Pandas.Dataframe.duplicated()` method to retrieve the duplicates from this dataframe like so:

```
In [16]: Merged[Merged.RegimentalNumber.duplicated() == True]
```

However, it looks like the result also includes missing values of `RegimentalNumber` as duplicates.

Does the `duplicated()` method take a flag or parameter to exclude missing values as duplicates? I took a look at the [API Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for this method but could not find such a flag.

Of course I can then simply exclude the missing values like this:

```
In [17]: duplicates = Merged[Merged.RegimentalNumber.duplicated() == True]
In [18]: duplicates[duplicates.RegimentalNumber.notnull()]
```

However, it doesn't seem right to me that the `duplicated()` method also includes missing values as duplicates. Is there a simpler, one step solution?

Comment: `duplicated` should treat `NaN` as `False` so you'll have to post raw data and code that reproduces what you're seeing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `df.dropna()` to ensure NULL values are ignored.
For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, np.nan, float('nan'), 
                           np.nan, float('nan'), 'xyz']})

print(df.dropna().loc[df['foo'].duplicated()])
```

yields

```
  foo
2   1
5   2
6   3
```

Note that `df['foo'].duplicated()` is a boolean Series whose index may be larger than `df.dropna().index`. However, when you select rows using `df.dropna().loc`, the boolean Series index is reindexed to match `df.dropna().index`, so the NULL values conveniently get dropped.